# Slide View out of Activity to reveal ListView underneath?

Tags: android, xml, listview, slidingmenu

[image: MainView revealing ListView underneath]
MainView revealing ListView underneath

My Problem is following. I'm trying to slide my main View which is a relative Layout, out of the way, to reveal a ListView underneath.

What I've got so far:

For now I was able to slide the ListView in. Animate it use fling gesture etc. But the ListView (View 2) is always on top of the bigger View 1 which is as wide as the whole layout.
I want it the other way round.

What I've tried so far:

I've tried setting a negative margin left side or positive margin right side to view one. The View however does not move out of the Layout but rather resizes itself so it fits in the small gap remaining.

I dont want it to resize tho. I want to be able to still see whatever is in the right part of View1. 
I've tried using a framelayout, the problem persists tho.

It seems to me, that in android the content, that matches parent width is always put underneath the other one.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#D3D3D3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="beyou_main_activities.ChattingActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >


    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/container_chatpart"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/messageText"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/messageContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="25dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLoadMore"
        style="@style/button_light_grey_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_load_more"
        />

       </LinearLayout>
       </ScrollView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonSmileys"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonSend"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonSmileys"
        android:background="#e7e5e5"
        android:ems="10"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonSmileys"
        style="@style/button_dark_red_white"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_smiley" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
        style="@style/button_dark_red_white"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/messageText"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_send"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_topics"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#2C2929"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical" >
    </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my code right now. I dont want to use the existing Sliding Menug libraries since they always move out all of the layout, including the action bar. I also already have a sliding menu on the left side, which would expanded be on top of view 1.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?